# Formatting HTML print

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have a report, that has a table, whcih could be occupying multiple pages.
In the table footer I need to have the some of all, i.e. I need single table footer to appear once, only at end of the report, not at end of each page.
[If any one can help how to get subtotals at end of each page will be deeply appreciated].

I wrote the below code, which also is loaded [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hasan3ysf/xvto9Lmy/2/).

The output is as below, whic is buggy.

HTML body:

```html
<body>
<h1>My page</h1>
<button onclick="printContent('t')">Print Content</button>

<div id="t">
 <div class="divHeader">Header</div>
 <br><br>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Heading</th>
        <th>Second Heading</th>
        <th>Third Heading</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    !-- so many rows of: --!
    <tr>
        <td>Green</td>
        <td>Yellow</td>
        <td>Orange</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot id="table_footer">
            <TR> <TH ALIGN=LEFT COLSPAN=2>Total</TH> <TH>4923</TH> </TR>
     </tfoot>
</table>
<br><br>
<div class="divFooter">Footer</div>
</div>
</body>
```

javascript for printing the required element:

```
<script language="javascript">
function printContent(el){
        var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
        var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
}
</script>
```

The styling:

```css
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        @page
        {
            size: auto;   /* auto is the current printer page size */
            margin: 20mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
            size: A4;
        }

        body
        {
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
            border: solid 1px black ;
       }
       .divFooter {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
        }
        .divHeader {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
        }
        table { page-break-after:auto }
        tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
        td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
        thead { display:table-header-group }
        tfoot { display:table-footer-group; page-break-after:auto }
    </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Any specific reason for this: `position: fixed;`

Comment: @Rajesh I need both header and footer to be in the exact top and bottom of the page.

Comment: So instead of having fixed elements, create 3 relative divs *header*, *body* and *footer*, and put all content inside *body*. This way, you have 1 element where you can have scroll and that is independent of *header*/ *footer*